# Tensorflow converged , but got a very low training accuracy using alexnet in mnist dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I wrote a tensoflow program to try Alexnet using MNIST dataset,but what is strange is my network converges very quickly,the loss almost doesn't change.And each batch accuracy is very low,below 0.1,such as following:

```
step 0   loss 2.29801 train_accuracy 0.14
step 100 loss 2.30258 train_accuracy 0.07
step 200 loss 2.30258 train_accuracy 0.15
step 300 loss 2.30258 train_accuracy 0.09
step 400 loss 2.30258 train_accuracy 0.08
step 500 loss 2.30258 train_accuracy 0.06
step 600 loss 2.30258 train_accuracy 0.15
step 700 loss 2.30258 train_accuracy 0.16
....
```

[**image like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF1yI.png)

and here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

data_dir='./minist'
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(data_dir,one_hot=True)

def conv2d(name, x, ws, bs, strides=1):
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(ws,stddev=0.01))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.,shape=bs))
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides=[1,strides,strides,1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x,b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x, name=name)

def maxpool2d(name, x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                      padding='SAME', name=name)
def fc_op(name, x, n_out):
    n_in = x.get_shape()[-1].value
    w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_in,n_out],stddev=0.01))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.,shape=[n_out]))
    x = tf.matmul(x, w)
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x, name=name)

def alex_net(x,num_classes):
    conv1 = conv2d('conv1', x, [11,11,1,96] , [96], strides=4)
    pool1 = maxpool2d('pool1', conv1)
    conv2 = conv2d('conv2', pool1, [5,5,96,256] , [256])
    pool2 = maxpool2d('pool2', conv2)
    conv3 = conv2d('conv3', pool2, [3,3,256,384] , [384])
    conv4 = conv2d('conv4', conv3, [3,3,384,384] , [384])
    conv5 = conv2d('conv5', conv4, [3,3,384,256] , [256])
    pool5 = maxpool2d('pool5', conv5)

    shp = pool5.get_shape()
    flattened_shape = shp[1].value*shp[2].value*shp[3].value
    resh = tf.reshape(pool5, shape=[-1,flattened_shape], name='resh')

    fc1 = fc_op('fc1', resh, 4096)
    fc2 = fc_op('fc2', fc1, 4096)
    fc3 = fc_op('fc3', fc2, num_classes)
    return fc3

# ############################ arguments setting
learning_rate = 0.01
train_steps= 8000
num_classes = 10  
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 784],dtype=tf.float32)
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
y=tf.placeholder(shape=[None,10],dtype=tf.float32)

output=alex_net(x_image,num_classes)  

# ################################### trian

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output,labels=y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# ###################################  inference
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred,tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)

for i in range(train_steps):
    xs, ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_op,feed_dict={x:xs,y:ys})
    if i%100==0:
        loss,train_accuracy = sess.run([cost,accuracy],feed_dict={x:xs,y:ys})
        print('step',i,'loss',loss,'train_accuracy',train_accuracy)
```

actually I tried not only MNIST but cifar-10,and it came to a same problem

Comment: Do you really need relu on the last fully-connected layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your network is having many layers and also the depth(number of filters) of each layer is very high. Also, you are training the network from scratch. And your dataset of MNIST (60000 images) is very little. Moreover, each MNIST image is only 28x28x1 size.

Couple of alternatives what I can suggest you is to retrain a pre-trained model, i.e do [transfer learning](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/). Look into this [AlexNet](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~guerzhoy/tf_alexnet/) weight file. The architecture is slightly different from what you have done in your code. Good thing about this way of implementation is, it will offset for very little data you have.

Other better alternative is to reduce the number of layers and number of filters in each layer. In this way, you will be able to train the model from scratch and also it will be very fast. (Assuming you don't have GPU). Take a look at [LeNet-5 architecture](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-01a.pdf).

Hope the answer helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I got a better consequence after I reduced convolution layers and used smaller learning rate in my networks .

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer and upvote it so that it will encourage me to answer more questions.